# Software for Imgur image upload

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, upload

Is there any software that can help me upload images directly to imgur.com?

Command line applications would be preferable.

Answer (score 10):

Imgur provides [tools](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/209592766-Tools-for-Imgur) for this. You can even download a [shell script from imgur.com](https://imgur.com/tools/imgurbash.sh) which works from the command line.

*Of course, installing software directly instead of using Ubuntu's [official repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) opens a **security hole** which makes GNU/Linux vulnerable to trojan malware. While usually not recommended, you can still do it, if you want to.* Here's how.

First, if you do not have a personal `bin` directory to store executables, create one by running the following commands:

```
cd
mkdir bin
source .profile
```

To download and install the imgur script, run the following commands (you do *not* need to be root):

```
wget http://imgur.com/tools/imgurbash.sh
chmod a+x imgurbash.sh
mv imgurbash.sh ~/bin/imgur
```

Now, simply run `imgur` with the path to an image to upload it to Imgur.

For example:

```
imgur /usr/share/banshee/icons/hicolor/128x128/devices/phone-google-nexus-one.png
```

This gives the following output:

```
http://i.imgur.com/SoIwv.png
Delete page: http://imgur.com/delete/VTtZOI9LOhtZ2oB
Haven't copied to the clipboard: no $DISPLAY
```

The first line is the link to the Imgur page, and the second line is the link to delete the image you just uploaded. If possible, the script will also copy the Imgur url to the clipboard for immediate use.

Enjoy!

*[Note: this answer previously suggested running the commands as **root** in order to put the imgur script into `/bin`. Using root should be avoided whenever possible. In this case, we can create a user's personal `~/bin` directory. It's an extra step, but the security is worth it.]*

Comment: +1 thanks a lot !! but ill wait for other answers

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind using a GUI:

[shutter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/shutter) [image: Install shutter]
is a feature-rich screenshot program. You can take a screenshot of a specific area, window, your whole screen, or even of a website – apply different effects to it, draw on it to highlight points, and then upload to an image hosting site, all within one window.

**Edit > Preferences**

[image: Preferences dialog]

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a slightly modified version of [Sirupsen's Linux Screenshot Uploader script](http://sirupsen.com/a-simple-imgur-bash-screenshot-utility) : https://gist.github.com/2941720

Install it like this:

```
curl https://imgur.com/tools/imgurbash.sh > ~/bin/imgur && chmod 755 ~/bin/imgur &&
curl https://gist.github.com/raw/2941720/shoot.sh > ~/bin/shoot && chmod 755 ~/bin/shoot
```

and call it (assuming `~/bin` is in your `PATH`) with `shoot`. Select the area of the screen you want to capture by drawing a rectangle around it and it'll capture that, upload to imgur and tell you the URL.

It internally uses `imgurbash.sh` but has a workaround if you don't want to install that dependency.

Comment: yes, indeed very good. It is not working as it is though. My proposed fixes are: sudo apt-get install scrot -y && mkdir -p ~/bin/ && ...your part. Cheers!

Comment: ANd it seems that the "shoot" raw link is also mistaken. I'm using this instead: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kynan/2941720/raw/ae2d619b0a5b8fae74fbaa49596c9b8e96abe148/shoot.sh