# How to Play Bulgarian/Cyrillic subtitles

Tags: vlc, subtitle, playback

Hello members I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS 32 bit my only problem is that I'm from Bulgaria and when a download movie with Bulgarian subs VLC player is not showing them properly how can i fix that ?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Would you please be more specific how the subtitles are not being shown properly? Maybe you can add an image to show what you mean?

Comment: yes I will show you screenshot if you just tell me how to upload picture hire ?

Comment: one possibility is to updload according http://askubuntu.com/questions/146888/software-for-imgur-image-upload or to http://www.imageshack.us/, and paste here the url they provide.

Comment: here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5276/how-do-i-include-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-question-in-askubuntu/5277#5277 they explain that you cannot paste an image directly on your question until you have enough reputation. Please provide the url as in my previous comment.

Comment: http://lookpic.com/O/i2/954/FiHD6Cu.png hope this will do the job

Comment: Please check; cannot open the image.

Answer (score 10):

I came here for help, but I found the answer myself.
In the VLC player menu, go to Tools, Preferences, Subtitles/OSD, then under Default Encoding choose Cyrillic (Windows-1251). You may need to restart the program in order for the change to take effect.

Успех! Ganbatte!

Answer (score 6):

It seems that your problem is related to the encoding of the subtitles. Check the instructions at [the VLC's page on subtitles](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Play_HowTo/Basic_Use/Subtitles) to adjust your preferences to whichever enconding was used to create the subtitle file.

Fonts in your Ubuntu installation should show cyrillic letters with no problem (anyway, that doesn't seem to be your problem).

If you need to change the encoding of your subtitle file, follow instructions given in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/277580/58950).

Comment: @Bodyshaker if the answer was helpful consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark, you can "upvote" it too.

Answer (score 0):

If your fonts doesn't display correctly with text editor then you can use reopen with encoding using sublime for example, then select the same encoding in VLC. VLC encoding wont be enough if you can't read the Cyrillic subtitles with your text editor. Example: reopen file with Cyrillic (Windows-1251) then set the same for default in VLC. [external link for more info](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/russian-encoding-symbols-incorrect-display/20874)