# Instant screenshot uploaders?

Tags: screenshot

The old thread is way outdated. Shutter doesnt even upload to anywhere anymore.

All I ask for is something like gyazo to upload to imgur. So pressing a button/hotkey would let me select part of a screen and then instantly upload. Without any dialog boxes, confirmations, logins etc. Preferably it'd be an applet(or whatever these thingies on the top right are called, indicators?).

I had an app that did exactly that on my old install, but I can't remember the name.

https://github.com/jomo/imgur-screenshot this returns me a syntax error when I want to run the .sh file every time in every version. I also would prefer to not use terminal.

EDIT: This thread has been identified as a duplicate, even though I have specified that the thread that's being linked has no good answers. Shutter does not work(nor is it instant). Nanoshot doesnt seem to exist anymore. Imgur screenshot is the only half-decent answer, but it provides no advantages over Gyazo. The biggest problem with Gyazo and Imgur-Uploader is when you select area, there seems to be a bug with scrot and visible "selection" lines, which sometimes draw over the actual screenshot. And opening the browser to take me to the image location really isnt something I want.

Comment: Possibly related to [How to take a screenshot and then upload the image to imgur through terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417295/how-to-take-a-screenshot-and-then-upload-the-image-to-imgur-through-terminal) (even if you're not interested in the first answer, using imgur-screenshot, still take a look at the other two)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a screenshot application which will auto-upload to imgur?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177921/whats-a-screenshot-application-which-will-auto-upload-to-imgur)

Comment: Author of imgur-screenshot here. Could you file an issue with details, please? It shouldn't return any syntax errors.

Comment: I've since then updated to 17.04 using gnome. And it started working after a reinstall. I might not have been using it correctly @jomo

Comment: v1.7.4 has been deprecated (although not due to a syntax error), please use v1.7.3. Glad you got it working though.

Comment: Please check if the last answer in the following question helps:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/146888/software-for-imgur-image-upload

Answer (score 1):

The default xfce screenshooter (with Xubuntu) does exactly what you need. Once you take the snap you can save it into your drive or upload to Imgur with no login whatsoever.

[image: see screenshot inception here]
(it says "*Upload to Imgur*" in Spanish)

Here's the file to download and install: http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/xfce4-screenshooter

Comment: Will this work on unity? I really like Unity. :D

Answer (score 0):

Gnome 17.04 has an extension that does exactly what I want it to do. You just have to change the settings(copy link to clipboard) after installing it from here:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/683/imgur-screenshot-uploader/